# Get Member Expression of custom property in ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, expandoobject

I'm creating a datagrid filter using `Expressions` in WPF. As my class I use `ExpandoObject` with both hardcoded and dynamically added properties. When I filter columns with static properties it works, but when I filter columns with dynamic properties i get an error that the property cannot be found.

```
// error here
var targetProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, Member);

// i.e.: parameter.Member.ToString().
var toStringCallExpression = Expression.Call(targetProperty, _toStringMethodInfo);

// i.e.: parameter.Member.ToString().Contains(Value).
return Expression.Call(toStringCallExpression, _containsMethodInfo, Expression.Constant(Value));
```

How can i get member expression of dynamic properties, that are not instance properties?

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be much more helpful.

Comment: What I can provide you else?

Comment: I wrote this response to a similar question some years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29431320/613130 Look if it is enough for you.

Comment: I've updated my question below. Can i get memberexpression in a similar way you mentioned?